# Ошибка AttributeError при создании Парсера на Python

Tags: python, парсер

Получаю одну ошибку:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?.

Как её починить?

КОД:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

def parser():
    URL = 'https://kwork.ru/projects?c=all'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36 OPR/80.0.4170.61 (Edition Yx GX)',
        'Accept': '*/*'
    }

    r = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'card want-card js-card-1431289 js-want-container'})
    projects = []
    title = items.find('div', {'class':'wants-card__header-title first-letter breakwords pr250'})
    projects.append(title)
    print(projects)

parser()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вложенность по тегам неверная: сначало парсим

```
'div' 'class':'wants-card__header-title first-letter breakwords pr250'
```

а потом только

```
'div', 'class':'card want-card js-card-1431289 js-want-container'
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests


URL = 'https://kwork.ru/projects?c=all'
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36 OPR/80.0.4170.61 (Edition Yx GX)',
    'Accept': '*/*'
    }

r = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_="wants-card__header-title first-letter breakwords pr250")

for i in items:
    url = i.find('a').get('href')
    text = i.text
    print(url, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод find_all возвращает список найденных тегов, а не объект класса BeautifulSoap. У списка нет метода find, по этому выходит ошибка.